# Group by array overlapping

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with id and clusters like this:

```
CREATE TABLE w (id bigint, clst int);
INSERT INTO w (id,clst)
VALUES 
  (1,0),
  (1,4),
  (2,1),
  (2,2),
  (2,3),
  (3,2),
  (4,2),
  (5,4),
  (6,5);
```

If you aggregate clusters grouped by id, you can see that there are overlapping values in the cluster arrays:

```
select id, array_agg(clst) clst from w group by id order by id;
 id |  clst
----+---------
  1 | {0,4}
  2 | {1,2,3}
  3 | {2}
  4 | {2}
  5 | {4}
  6 | {5}
```

i.e. cluster 4 covers id 1 and 5, cluster 2 covers id 2, 3 and 4, whereas cluster 5 corresponds only to one id.

How can I now aggregate ids grouped by cluster arrays overlapping?
i.e. the expected result is:

```
 id      | clst
---------+-------
 {1,5}   | {0,4,4}
 {2,3,4} | {1,2,3,2,2}
 {6}     | {5}
```

I don't care much about the cluster column just need ids properly aggregated.

There is no restriction on number of possible overlappings. Number of clusters per id is not restricted either (it can be hundreds or even more). Clusters are assined to ids not sequenctially.

There are millions of rows in the table!!!

Using PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: The logic of how to do the grouping is missing.  So is your DDL.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the desired logic.

Comment: Why should 1,2 exist at all?  Why should it (1,2) be grouped with 1,2,3?  Why is 3 grouped with only 4?

Comment: @MichaelKutz sorry for unclarity. I have rewritten the question completely this time.

Comment: What's the max. possible length of chains like `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,4]` etc? Any restriction at all? If not, this is very hard on set-based solutions. Anything else you can tell us about cluster arrays? Are numbers arbitrary or ranges without gaps like your example seems to suggest? Cardinality? Range of possible IDs and cluster-numbers? Min/max/median/avg number of clusters per array. *Any* meta-information is crucial to keep performance in check here. Start with your version of Postgres and your *actual* table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) clarifying data types and constraints.

Comment: I've tried to provide the answers to your questions in the original question. Please check it now.

Comment: your test data isn't quite consistent — you variously use `w` and `t` for the table name and zero-based and 1-based indexes for clst.

Comment: Have corrected that.

Comment: does 'overlapping' mean 'share a cluster id'? so {1,3} does not overlap with {2}?

Comment: yes, when I say overlapping, I mean that cluster arrays have some value in common. e.g.  {0,4} overlapps with {4}, but not with {1,2,3}

Comment: There are no constraints on table `w`? Really? `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `NOT NULL`,  .. ? This seems wrong. Please provide proper information from the start. This way you are wasting time of people trying to help.

Comment: Erwin, the sample table w is a result of join selection from other tables which is out of the topic. So there are no unique, primary key or not null contrains, but there are no null values for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't care much about the cluster column just need ids properly aggregated.

In that case we can make use of the `uniq` and `sort` functions in [the intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/intarray.html):

> ```
> with recursive a as (
>   select id, array_agg(distinct clst) clst from w group by id)
> , t(id,pid,clst) as (
>   select id,id,clst from a
>   union all
>   select t.id,a.id,t.clst|a.clst
>   from t join a on a.id<>t.pid and t.clst&&a.clst and not t.clst@>a.clst)
> , d as (
>   select distinct on(id) id, clst from t order by id, cardinality(clst) desc)
> select array_agg(id), clst from d group by clst;
> ```
>
> ```
> array_agg | clst   
> :-------- | :------
> {6}       | {5}    
> {2,3,4}   | {1,2,3}
> {1,5}     | {0,4}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66ac9ce505fe79641fd6e6e2f467511d&hide=3)*

Bear in mind that this is unlikely to perform well on millions of rows.

Comment: You can replace `uniq(sort(t.clst||a.clst))` with `t.clst | a.clst` for better performance. `|` being the custom "union" operator provided by intarray that returns sorted arrays implicitly.

Comment: @Erwin thanks, that's a handy tip :) The intarray documentation could be a bit clearer on what the union operators do, ie whether they guarantee a sorted output.

Comment: @JackDouglas: Sadly, no guarantees in the manual. I looked up the source code [here](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/__int__op_8c.html#a325f448911d95050b3b4bc5fc49512c6) and [here](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/__int_8h.html#a0489f7887c5a229863b0307422f9a34b), and it definitely returns a sorted list of unique elements. Still just an implementation detail. If that's too vague, the sure way would be `sort(t.cls | a.clst)`. Still faster than before and at least uniqueness is guaranteed from the union operator.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin — at the end of the day performance is likely to be the killer without some other kind of 'constraint', as [you said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235318/group-by-array-overlapping/235375?noredirect=1#comment464585_235318), still it's a fun problem :)