# Grouping by overlapping arrays, transitively, without duplicates

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array, recursive

I've found:

- [Group by array overlapping](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/235318/104401)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650080/5419599

However, I'm having trouble putting it to use in my case.

I have a table like so (the real `myid` values are hashes, but simplified here for illustration):

```
create temp table a (myid text, ip inet);
insert into a (myid, ip)
values
  ('0a', '10.10.1.1'),
  ('0a', '10.10.1.2'),
  ('0a', '10.10.1.3'),
  ('0b', '10.10.1.2'),
  ('0b', '10.10.1.4'),
  ('0c', '10.10.1.5'),
  ('0d', '10.10.1.3'),
  ('0e', '10.10.1.6'),
  ('0e', '10.10.1.7'),
  ('0f', '10.10.1.8'),
  ('0f', '10.10.1.9'),
  ('10', '10.10.1.9'),
  ('11', '10.10.1.10'),
  ('12', '10.10.1.11'),
  ('12', '10.10.1.4'),
  ('1a', '10.10.1.2'),
  ('1a', '10.10.1.4'),
  ('1e', '10.10.1.11'),
  ('1f', '10.10.1.12'),
  ('23', '10.10.1.12');
```

The result I can't work out how to produce is:

```
         ids         |                         ips
---------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 {0a,0b,0d,12,1a,1e} | {10.10.1.1,10.10.1.2,10.10.1.3,10.10.1.4,10.10.1.11}
 {0c}                | {10.10.1.5}
 {0e}                | {10.10.1.6,10.10.1.7}
 {0f,10}             | {10.10.1.8,10.10.1.9}
 {11}                | {10.10.1.10}
 {1f,23}             | {10.10.1.12}
```

The logic here is that any ids with ips in common are grouped together, *transitively*.  For instance, `0a` has an ip in common with `0b`; `0b` has one in common with `12`; `12` has one in common with `1e`, and so forth.

There are tens of thousands of rows, no specific limit on how many ips for any given id, and no specific limit on how many ids may show any given ip.

I know how to aggregate by ip, or aggregate by id, but doing *both* transitively is giving me trouble.  I tried a recursive CTE but I couldn't seem to get it right, and I'm not sure if that was the right approach in the first place.  (If I could first group by id and then group by overlapping array of ips, and avoid duplicates in the aggregation, I would be all set, but there may be a better approach.)

Is there a way to produce the above results with standard SQL?  Or at least with standard Postgres?  (I'm using 9.6.6.)

---

Here is a failed attempt.  (It is a legal query that does return results, but not the desired results.)  It fails because:

1. It includes intermediate results rather than replacing them with later results, and
2. It doesn't sort the array concatenations, so it includes each result multiple times.  This is also a hugely slow query for the actual dataset I am working with, since it returns up to `n!` times each result.

Here is the query:

```
with recursive b as (
  select
    array[myid] as ids,
    array_agg(ip) as ips 
  from a
  group by myid
), c as (
  select
    ids,
    ips
  from b
  union
  select
    b.ids || c.ids,
    b.ips || c.ips
  from
    b
    join c on
      (not b.ids && c.ids)
      and (b.ips && c.ips)
)
select * from c
;
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the key parts of Jack Douglas's solution in [Group by array overlapping](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235318/group-by-array-overlapping) is the `|` (pipe) operator used on arrays in the recursive part of the recursive `t` CTE like this:

```
...
select t.id, a.id, t.clst | a.clst
...
```

This operator concatenates two arrays suppressing duplicate items. The reason that answer cannot be directly applied to your setup is because apparently the `|` operator is defined for `int` arrays only, while you need a way to perform the same operation on `inet` arrays.

You can do that by treating the arrays as row sets. If you notice, what the `|` operator produces is effectively a union of two sets. Therefore, if you `unnest` both arrays, `union` them and aggregate the combined set back as an array, you will get the same result. So, this expression,

```
t.clst | a.clst
```

can be replaced with a correlated subquery:

```
(
  select
    array_agg(sub.n)
  from
    (
      select unnest(t.clst)
      union
      select unnest(a.clst)
    ) as sub (n)
)
```

Yes, the substitution is quite unwieldy in comparison, but it does the job, and that is something to start with.

Adapting the solution to your example (and adding a bit of white space to the original code), the complete query would look like this:

```
with recursive
  cte_a as
  (
    select
      myid,
      array_agg(distinct ip) as ip
    from
      a
    group by
      myid
  )
, cte_t (myid, pmyid, ip) as
  (
    select
      myid,
      myid,
      ip
    from
      cte_a

    union all

    select
      t.myid,
      a.myid,

      (  /* this is the replacement expression */
        select
          array_agg(sub.n)
        from
          (
            select unnest(t.ip)

            union

            select unnest(a.ip)
          ) as sub (n)
      )

    from
      cte_t as t
      join cte_a as a
        on a.myid <> t.pmyid and t.ip && a.ip and not t.ip @> a.ip
  )
, cte_d as
  (
    select distinct on (myid)
      myid,
      ip
    from
      cte_t
    order by
      myid,
      cardinality(ip) desc
  )
select
  array_agg(myid),
  ip
from
  cte_d
group by
  ip
;
```

You can test the query in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5ecdc088c8e3bdc9f853fdbffd5bfcb6) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk.

Note also that Jack's word of caution probably applies to your situation as well:

> Bear in mind that this is unlikely to perform well on millions of rows.